# Removing the word "Chapter n"

Tags: sectioning, chapters

So I am trying to *remove* the words `Chapter n`, and replace it by the `chapter title`. BUT I want it to show up in the table of contents... (So I cannot use `\chapter*{...}`).

Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use `titlesec`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Some chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
\chapter*{Introduction}\stepcounter{chapter}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
```

Place that code at the beginning of your chapter.

Comment: In this case did you loose the previous definition of `\chapter*`? Which just do not enumerate it, if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `book` or `report` document class, and if you don't want to employ a LaTeX package such as `titlesec`, you could proceed by redefining (simplifying, really) the low-level macro `\@makechapterhead`. Here's a working example that uses the `book` document class; tthe lines starting with `%%` are commented out from the original code of `\@makechapterhead`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %%\vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    %%\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      %%\if@mainmatter
      %%  \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
      %%  \par\nobreak
      %%  \vskip 20\p@
      %%\fi
    %%\fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
\newcommand{\mychapter}{#1}{%
\chapter*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
```

It looks like it works for me.  I can't guarantee that it will for you
though.

Comment: For this to work, don't you also need an instruction such as `\refstepcounter{chapter}`, to increment the `chapter` counter?

Comment: @Mico good point.  Didn't think of that.

Comment: This looks like the simplest solution. Why no more up votes, at least?

Answer (score 0):

Add  in preamble such a line

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will not only remove the chapter number, but all numbers, also those of sections, subsections etc. It will also remove the numbers in the table of contents, which is not what the OP wants.