# Remove word "chapter" fancyhrd

Tags: chapters, fancyhdr

I want to remove the word `chapter` from the page, where the new chapter begins. The code I got from sharelatex.com (template: German lab and course report).

This is the code of the `hgbheadings.sty`:

```
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\@ifundefined{chapter}%
   {}%
     {\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
            \ifthenelse{\value{chapter} < 1}%
                {\markboth{#1}{}}%
                {\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
        }}


\addtolength{\headheight}{\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %% thin line under header
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %% no line under header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}                            %% Clear all fields.
%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\thepage} %{\bf \rightmark}
%\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\sffamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}  %{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\sffamily\thepage} %{\bf \rightmark}
\fancyhead[L]{\sffamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}  %{\slshape \leftmark}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily\thepage} % except the center
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

The tex file:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{hgbheadings}
\begin{document}
%%%----------------------------------------------------------
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
%%%----------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{Guidelines}
%%%----------------------------------------------------------

Here are a few guidelines for the reports expected to be turned in for this course.

One chapter should be provided for each assignment.
Describe the given task in your own words (do not replicate the assignment 1:1). 
Then describe your approach, explain the main difficulties, clearly outline your solution, finally provide illustrative and meaningful results. 

%
\begin{center}
\textbf{Don't just show your program code!} 
\end{center}
%
\chapter{Texture Segmentation}
%%%----------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}

Description of this task follows here.
```

The `\documentclass` is report. I already read the other questions of stackexchange relating to my topic, but I couldn't solve my problem. How can I remove the **Chapter 1** and change the title of the chapter into **1 Chaptertitle**?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241684/removing-the-word-chapter-n?rq=1

Comment: @Rmano This would also remove the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `fancyhdr`: you have to modify the definition of `\@makechapterhead`. I made a single example file, it will be easy to implement the change in your `.sty` file.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter

% addition for not showing 'Chapter 1'
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \thechapter\nobreakspace
    \fi
    #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}


\@ifundefined{chapter}%
   {}%
     {\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
            \ifthenelse{\value{chapter} < 1}%
                {\markboth{#1}{}}%
                {\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
        }}


\addtolength{\headheight}{\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %% thin line under header
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %% no line under header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}                            %% Clear all fields.
%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\thepage}
%\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\sffamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\sffamily\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\sffamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily\thepage} % except the center
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%%%----------------------------------------------------------
%\maketitle
\tableofcontents
%%%----------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{Guidelines}
%%%----------------------------------------------------------

Here are a few guidelines for the reports expected to be turned in for this course.

One chapter should be provided for each assignment.
Describe the given task in your own words (do not replicate the assignment 1:1). 
Then describe your approach, explain the main difficulties, clearly outline your 
solution, finally provide illustrative and meaningful results. 

%
\begin{center}
\textbf{Don't just show your program code!} 
\end{center}

\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Texture Segmentation}

\lipsum[1-10]
%%%----------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\nobreakspace` you might want `\quad`.

[image]