# Generate TOC with custom chapter names

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

I am trying to write a book which will mostly be a collection of many PDF files.
At this time I have this structure:

```
%main.tex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}                                                                                  
\usepackage{pdfpages}                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                            
\begin{document}                                                                                                            
\tableofcontents                                                                                                            
\include{pdf-1}                                                                                                             
\include{pdf-2}                                                                                                             
\end{document}

%pdf-1.tex
\pagenumbering{arabic}                                                                                                      
\chapter{First chapter}                                                                                                     
\pagebreak                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                            
\includepdf{pdf1.pdf}

%pdf-2.tex
\chapter{Second chapter}                                                                                                    
\pagebreak                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                            
\includepdf{pdf2.pdf}
```

The TOC gets generated, but latex insists on inserting the text "Chapter 1" and "Chapter 2" in the PDF. I would prefer to have my own chapter names.

Comment: What about `\chapter*{First chapter}` ... `\chapter*{Second chapter}`?

Comment: the options of the book class are a bit restricted here, you would have to redefine `\@makechapterhead` or use a package like titlesec, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241693/2388. Other classes like memoir or the koma classes have more options.